# React Native Typescript - Problem with Ref type

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-ref

I'm trying to pass down to my component a ref but I'm having some problems with typescript types.. If someone could help it will be much appreciated

---

./Privacy.tsx

const Privacy = () => {

```
const buttonRef = useRef();

return <Button title="test" ref={(ref) => buttonRef = ref}/>
```

}

---

./Button.tsx

type Props = {
title: string,
ref?: What do i need to put here?
}

const Button: React.FC = ({ title, ref }) => {

```
return 
    <View ref={ref} />
```

}

Answer (score -1):

`ref` can not be passed directly via props if you want to pass a `ref` from parent to another custom component you have to use `React.forwardRef`. For example,

```js
const Privacy = () => {
  const buttonRef = useRef();

  return <Button title="test" ref={buttonRef} />;
};

interface ButtonProps extends React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> {
  title: string;

  // other props you want to pass to the button component
}

const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  (props, ref) => { 
    const { title } = props;  

    return <button ref={ref}>Hello</button>;
  }
);
```

Keep in mind that the first argument to the `Button` component will the `props` that you will pass and the second argument will be the `ref` object.

Read more about [forwarding refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html)